# Transition slide to the left

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating a slideshow where the first item grows bigger as you click between slides. This works fine. However I am not able to add a nice smooth transition to the left when you click through the slideshow. What am I doing wrong? I tried using jquery animate and also css transitions. Nothing happens.

https://codepen.io/camwes89/pen/mdJQLra

```js
var slider = $(".grow-carousel"),
  item_width = slider.parent().outerWidth();

// Adjust the slider when/if the window gets resized
$(window).on("resize", adjust);
adjust();

if (slider.children("li").length > 1) {
  // Add previous/next buttons
  slider
    .parent()
    .append(
      '<a href="#" id="btn-prev"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i><span>Previous</span></a><a href="#" id="btn-next"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i><span>Next</span></a>'
    );

  // Handle clicks on the next button
  slider.parent().on("click", "a#btn-prev", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".grow-carousel li").removeClass("active");
    slider.children("li:last").prependTo(slider);
    slider.css("left", -item_width);
    slider.animate({
        left: 0
      },
      300,
      "swing"
    );

    slider.find("li").first().addClass("active");
  });

  // Handle clicks on the previous button
  slider.parent().on("click", "a#btn-next", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".grow-carousel li").removeClass("active");
    slider.animate({
        left: -item_width
      },
      300,
      "swing",
      function() {
        slider.children("li:first").appendTo(slider);
        slider.css("left", 0);
        slider.find("li").first().addClass("active");
      }
    );
  });
}

// Helpers
function adjust() {
  item_width = slider.parent().outerWidth();
  slider
    .children("li")
    .width(item_width)
    .parent()
    .width(item_width * slider.children("li").length);
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400x;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  transition: all 3s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  li {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 80px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #333;
    height: 260px;
    width: 160px !important;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    transition-delay: 250ms;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    img {
      height: 100%;
      width: auto;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    &.active {
      height: 300px;
    }
  }
}

#btn-next {
  position: relative;
  top: -29px;
  margin-left: 101px;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 2px 3px;
}

#btn-prev {
  position: relative;
  top: -29px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 2px 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <ul class="grow-carousel">
    <li>
      <div>
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1585194329143-ad92c5b1ede0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" />
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1585001994793-7a4b117bcdcb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" />
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1585225465920-594394872d48?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" /></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you have a 'not really working' animation when clicking on Previous or Next button. The rendering effect is a jump in the animation... right?

**You main problem is a conflict beetween CSS animation & JQUERY animation**

It seems you want to rule all by JS (with jQuery) because you need to move the last or first image of your slideshow before or after the animation. The used property for animation is `left`, which is animated or simply set.

So far, so good.... BUT, you have side effects because this `left` property is also animated with CSS (3 second duration). Each time you are touching `left` property with JS, it lasts 3 second, so all your JS concept / animation is ruined.

You just need to

1. Comment the CSS animation for your `ul` element
2. Increase you animation duration from 100ms to 2s for instance

**Keep in mind you should not mix CSS animation  and JQUERY animation on same properties unless you really know what you are doing**

Something that works for me with these 2 updates
https://jsfiddle.net/piiantom/a79b2gn4/11/

*PS: Beware of your comments which are reversed compared to the applied dedicated code on Prev / Next buttons*

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Exacly what I was going for. Have a great weekend :)